# How to read a single character from a NetworkStream object in C#?

Tags: c#, stream

I am looking for an effient way of reading a single character from a networkStream objects.
With **NetworkStream.Read** method you can read an array byte not a single character.

Here is what i have tried but i got stuck after getting an array of characters

```
  public char readChar(NetworkStream networkStreamObj)
  {
      byte[] bytesArray = new byte[8129];
      int n = networkStreamObj.Read(bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length);
      char[] charArray = new char[Encoding.ASCII.GetCharCount(bytesArray, 0, n)];
      /**Need help after this line**/
  }
```

Note that i tried another alternative by using a StreamReader object but i got the error saying that the stream was unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are reading ASCII, all you need is:

```
int byte = stream.ReadByte();
if(byte < 0) // hadle EOF
else return (char) byte;
```

In the more general case, when encodings may be multi-byte, you should use a TextReader, for example a StreamReader. This is *designed* to handle text reading (over an arbitrary `Encoding`) from a stream.

i.e. using UTF-8

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
    ... consume the class
}
```

and

```
int next = reader.Read();
if(next < 0) // handle EOF
else {
    char c = (char)next;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc! With streamReader i got an exception error "Stream was unreadable" ! What could be the cause of that error?

Comment: CanRead returns false! I think a networkStream object can be readable and writable at the same time, am i wrong?

Comment: @Xris that depends entirely on how the stream is created (and, of course, whether it is open)